# Trying to get property 'videos' of non-object

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, properties, laravel-blade

I am trying to get each models video. And I am getting non-object error.

Controller:

```
public function index() 
    {
        $model_video = NewModelVideos::all();

        return view('admin.model_new_videos.index')
        ->with('model_video', $model_video);
    }
```

Model:

```
public function videos()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\NewModels', 'model_id');
    }
```

View:

```
{{$model->videos->video}}
```

Comment: What you have in `$model` variable? from controller you are returning 'model_video'...

Comment: sorry I forgot to add this @foreach($model_video as $model)

Comment: the `$model->videos` is a `Eloquent Collection` you are not allowed to access the `video`property through it! You need to loop through the `$model->videos`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$model->videos` is a `Eloquent Collection` you are not allowed to access the `video`property through it! You need to loop through the `$model->videos`:

```
@foreach ($model_video as $model)

    @foreach ($model->videos as $video) 

          {{ $video->something }}

    @endforeach

@endforeach
```